# How do I refer to current column during np.select?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When using the np.select function,
I'd like to refer to the values of the current column I am appending it on, and set a
value based on a condition

Problem:
On the code below, my conditions are referring to the 'Profit' column where np.select would assign a value to it, but somehow my code does not obey these conditions.

In the 'Profit' column, when I would set a value of **1 Month**, the value of the cell on top of it has to be 'Yes'.

Example code:

```
conditions = [
    (df['UserID'].shift() == df['UserID']) & (df['totalSold'] >= df['totalBought']),
    (df['UserID'].shift() == df['UserID']) & (df['totalSold'] >= df['totalBought']) & (df['Profit'].shift() == 'Yes'),
(df['UserID'].shift() == df['UserID']) & (df['totalSold'] >= df['totalBought']) & (df['Profit'].shift() == '1 Month')]

values = ['Yes', '1 Month', '2 Month']

df['Profit'] = np.select(conditions, values, default = "No")
```

Input Dataframe:

| id | month | totalBought | totalSold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Jan | 200 | 300 |
| aaa | Feb | 250 | 300 |
| aaa | March | 100 | 350 |
| bbb | Jan | 100 | 150 |

Expected Output dataframe:

| id | month | totalBought | totalSold | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Jan | 200 | 300 | Yes |
| aaa | Feb | 250 | 300 | 1 Month |
| aaa | March | 100 | 350 | 2 Month |
| bbb | Jan | 100 | 150 | Yes |

Comment: Which one is your original input dataframe?

Comment: Do you mean the dataframe that I currently am outputting?

Comment: No, I want to know what is the dataframe you're starting out with. Is it the first one? I know what your expected output is, but from the question, it's not perfectly clear what you start with.

Comment: Re-edited the question, I specified the dataframe I started out with. Yes its the first one, just wanted to add a new column called 'Profit', and respective values based on the conditions

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something a little more dynamic, like this:

```
ge_mask = df['totalSold'].diff().fillna(-1).ge(0)
df['Profit'] = np.select([ge_mask, df['totalSold'].ge(df['totalBought'])], [ge_mask.cumsum().astype(str) + ' Month', 'Yes'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    id  month  totalBought  totalSold   Profit
0  aaa    Jan          200        300      Yes
1  aaa    Feb          250        300  1 Month
2  aaa  March          100        350  2 Month
3  bbb    Jan          100        150      Yes
```